# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header on one site, but not on another

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api, cors

We have a system made up of a website, written in ASP.NET/MVC, and a webservices site, written in ASP.NET/WEBAPI. The user loads pages from the website, which make AJAX calls into the webservices site, using JQuery.

We're building this with VS2013, and deploying it with MS's Web Deploy, run from jobs configured in Jenkins, so there's not a lot of opportunity for someone to fumble-finger something during the install.

Our problem - when we deploy the two sites to our QA environment, things work fine. We can access the webservice and load the pages, they make AJAX calls to the webservices, and Bob's your uncle.

But when we deploy the two sites to our TEST environment, we're getting:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://mntest.ktws.XXX.com/api/Motd/getMotdHtml. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://mntest.XXX.com' is therefore not
>   allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

And here's the odd thing - the URL of the webservices site is stored in the website's web.config. If we manually edit the web.config of the website on the test environment, and point it to the webservices site on the QA environment, everything is working fine.

I've done a diff, on the web.configs of the webservices site in QA and in TEST, and aside from different server names in the database connection strings, they're identical. I have no idea why the two sites are behaving differently.

We've code in place, that's supposed to handle CORS calls.  In Global.asax.cs, we have implemented Application_BeginRequest:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var origin = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["origin"];
    if (origin != null)
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);

    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == HttpMethod.Options.Method)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "DELETE,GET,HEAD,POST,PUT,TRACE");

        // Accept whatever headers they've asked to send us
        var requestedHeaders = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Access-Control-Request-Headers"];
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", requestedHeaders);

        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");

        // This aborts the response, ending any future processing. Which is always a bad idea, except when it isn't.
        // (It seems to be the usual process in dealing with HttpOPTIONS)
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
}
```

When we make the call against the webservice in QA, we see this in the request:

```
GET http://vm-qaweb2.XXX.net/XXX_webservice/api/Motd/getMotdHtml HTTP/1.1
Host: vm-qaweb2.XXX.net
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: http://mntest.XXX.com
authenticationToken: undefined
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.124 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://mntest.XXX.com/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

And this in the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://mntest.XXX.com
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 17 Jun 2015 21:26:43 GMT
Content-Length: 1064

[The expected content for the message-of-the-day]
```

Make the call against the webservice in TEST, we see this in the request:

```
OPTIONS http://mntest.ktws.XXX.com/api/Motd/getMotdHtml HTTP/1.1
Host: mntest.ktws.XXX.com
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://mntest.XXX.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.124 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, authenticationtoken
Accept: */*
Referer: http://mntest.XXX.com/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

And we see this in the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 17 Jun 2015 21:30:58 GMT
Content-Length: 1136
Set-Cookie: NSC_UFTU!L1-WNXFC0-1=ffffffffc3a02c7445525d5f4f58455e445a4a423660;expires=Thu, 18-Jun-2015 05:28:54 GMT;path=/;httponly

[The expected content for the message-of-the-day]
```

And in Chrome's developer tools, we see the error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://mntest.ktws.XXX.com/api/Motd/getMotdHtml. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://mntest.XXX.com' is therefore not
>   allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

For what it's worth, the getMotdHtml() controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("getMotdHtml")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public string getMotdHtml()
{
    try
    {
        string html = "";
        html = this.motdWrangler.getMotdHtml();
        return html;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        try
        {
            this.logger.logException(ex, "Exception in getMotdHtml");
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

It's not returning a 404 response, no matter what happens. Yet we're getting a 404 status code. What makes it particularly confusing is that our response contains the expected message-of-the-day text, which it could only have obtained if it had executed the getMotdHtml() action. But if it had, why the 404, and why isn't Access-Control-Allow-Origin being returned in the response, when Application_BeginRequest() had to have added it?

Keep in mind, these aren't two different applications - it's the same build being deployed to two different servers. On one, it works, on the other, it doesn't, despite there being no relevant differences in the web.configs.

Help?

Comment: Is there a significant difference between `http://mntest.ktws.XXX.com/` and `http://mntest.XXX.com/`?

Comment: maybe i should read the whole question

Comment: The problem here is your TEST environment is sending a preflight, while your QA environment is not (note GET vs OPTIONS).There are a few things that can cause a preflight, but, i'd suggest just making your backend support preflight requests rather than going down the road of preventing them.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with web-api to provide an answer, however, you should be able to come up with one from the documentation here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: We're not trying to prevent preflights. We want to support them. We're at a loss as to why we're seeing preflights in QA, but not in TEST. Given, that is, that it's the same code running in both environments. (Same browser on the client, as well.)

Comment: And mntest.ktws.XXX.com and mntest.XXX.com route to two different web applications on the same server, one the website and the other the webservices site.

Comment: When you connect to TEST vs QA, is your internet zone different? Intranet vs Public? Do you get the same results in all browsers? Something is causing the TEST environment to send a preflight, and your server isn't responding to them. Note, use @commentername to notify me when you make a comment, otherwise i may miss it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem might have been that one of the servers had WebDAV installed:

http://brockallen.com/2012/10/18/cors-iis-and-webdav/

I added these changes to the web.config, and the error we had been seeing went away.  (We are, of course, now seeing different problems, unrelated to this, but then, this is programming ;)